# RLS in PowerApps

Tags: sql, powerapps, row-level-security

I have a Azure SQL server and 3 security groups on Azure AD who are added as external users in Azure SQL.  The Azure SQL has a filter predicate based upon the security group that the logged in user belongs to.  When I am on SSMS and log in as different users, I can see the filtering from the filter predicate.  It is working exactly as intended.

Now the problem.

I have a PowerApps for which the same Azure AD is used to log in. However, post log in, there is no filtering.  I am flummoxed how the filter predicate works in SSMS but not in the PowerApps studio.  I do not have Azure AD connector in PowerApps - I am using the Office groups connector (if that is any reason?).

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you select `Azure AD Integrated` or `Windows Authentication (Non-shared)` when you connected the SQL data source?

[image]

If not, you're **Implicitly** sharing your connection with all users of the PowerApp rather than leveraging the AD SQL permissions you set up.

**REF**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/sql-server-security

Answer (score 0):

I selected the Azure AD authentication. Essentially, both the PowerApps and the SQL database are authenticated by the same AD directory. As explained earlier, the predicate works exactly as intended on SSMS. When I log in as different SQL user I can see only a limited number of rows as intended. However the PowerApps (authenticated by Azure AD for the users allowed to access the app) does not respect the RLS. Just can’t seem to find where the problem is. Since the issue is conceptual I have not pasted code. However I am happy to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have published the PowerApps and tried to see if it will respect the RLS when published. It does not - thereby further establishing that the RLS doesn’t work. I have used the office groups connector - as I do not have the required permissions for the Azure AD connector